# Adding "with escape characters" tag to a .txt file

Tags: file

I am trying to print out the contents of a .txt file using cat and have it appear with the ansi colors, although one file will print out the ASCII image with color the other will not. The only difference I can find is that one includes a "ASCII text, with escape characters" tag and the other file only contains "ASCII text".

I've not been able to find a way to add the "tag" to the .txt file and I dont want to have to change the file extension. I know that I could create a sh script to echo out the text in color using `echo "$(tput setaf 4) Hello World! $(tput sgr 0)"` but the current motd file is not run, just printed out using cat. Im using Debian on an arm cpu `uname -a : Linux landcap 4.14.24-sunxi #3 SMP Thu Mar 8 13:45:10 MST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Files both contain the same content, but print differently
`file escape.txt` prints `escape.txt: ASCII text, with escape sequences`
`file NewFile.txt` prints `NewFile.txt: ASCII text`

Both files contain

```
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m              `.-..........`              ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m             `////////::.`-/.             ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m             -: ....-////////.            ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m             //:-::///////////`           ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m      `--::: `-://////////////:           ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m      //////-    ``.-:///////// .`        ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m      `://////:-.`    :///////::///:`     ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m        .-/////////:---/////////////:     ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;31m           .-://////////////////////.     ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m          yMN+`.-^[[0m^[[1;31m::///////////////-`      ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m       .-`:NMMNMs`  `..-------..`         ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m        MN+/mMMMMMhoooyysshsss            ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m MMM    MMMMMMMMMMMMMMyyddMMM+            ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m  MMMM   MMMMMMMMMMMMMNdyNMMh`     hyhMMM ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m   MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMyoNNNMMM+.   MMMMMMMM  ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m    MMNMMMNNMMMMMNM+ mhsMNyyyyMNMMMMsMM   ^[[0m
                                                                                   ^[[0m^[[1;37m                                          ^[[0m
```

Which should print with a red hat and a white body

Comment: Possibly useful https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/262185/display-file-with-ansi-colors

Comment: The issue is they are using echo and different escape sequences to print the color

Answer (score 0):

The characters in your example are not actually embedded escape. They are the literal ^ and [ characters.  Some editors display an embedded escape with those characters, but being literal and embedded is different.  I was able to copy paste your example to a text file and using vim I replaced the literal ^[ with an embedded escape.  After that when I just cat the file it showed up in red and white.

If you know vim, the way I embedded the escape was using the substitute command:

`%s/old/new/g`

for old I put   `\^\[`    for new I typed `ctrl-v` then the `escape` key.